# degree symbol is change to question mark when i output my data from my DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

How come when the degree sign in my database was change to a question mark when i ouput the data on my webpage..

the collation of my data is latin1_swedish_ci
on my webpage the meta is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: `latin1` != `utf8` also it's anyone guess as to what you are telling the DB driver to connect with.